# Problem with Qt::QueuedConnection, signal delivered after disconnect

Tags: qt

I just discovered interesting behavior of queued connection in Qt 4.6:

First queued connection is made:

```
connect(someSender, SIGNAL(completed()), this, SLOT(handleCompletion()), Qt::QueuedConnection)
```

Then someSender sends the signal:

```
emit completed()
```

Before receiving signal (as it is in queue), I disconnect from the signal:

```
disconnect(someSender, SIGNAL(completed()), this, SLOT(handleCompletion())
```

Still, handleCompletion slot is invoked at next eventloop iteration. I can prevent this from happening by using someSender->blockSignals(true) at correct point, but it feels awful not to mention having some boolean flag to disable slot's functionality.

Especially, I feel amazed that this behavior is not mentioned in Qt documentation (at least I haven't found).

Finally the question: any sensible way to avoid this from happening?

Comment: I guess the way Qt::QueuedConnection is implemented is queue on the receiver side (event loop), so everything that emitted before disconnect() should go into that queue and stay there until it is processed.
Probably you want to call disconnect() in sync with signal emiting. In other case there is no big difference if that signal will be handled or not, because handleCompletion() can complete earlier for older events and in your expected scenario completed() will be processed. I.e. if you didn't specified straight scenario of thread interaction your program can work as it want to work.

Comment: If you want you could go and hack the Qt code, it's quite well written.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Qt is behaving in the most intuitive way.

When you do `emit completed()`, it makes sense for the signal to immediately activate or queue all connected slots.  If queued slots could be unqueued as a result of a disconnect, it would be more difficult to understand, and more prone to race conditions.  Also, consider more complex scenarios: e.g. so if disconnecting removes it from the queue, does reconnecting put it back?

If it worked the way you'd expected, then in place of this question there'd be "Problem with Qt::QueuedConnection, signal not delivered after disconnect".

As for the sensible way to avoid this: you should redesign your code so that neither the sender nor receiver have to care if the signal is connected directly or queued.  I'd recommend that neither the sender nor receiver calls `QObject::connect` and this is done by a third class.  It's not clear if this will entirely solve your problem, it depends on where and why you're doing the `disconnect`.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable. I still would find usable if there would be support for "unqueueing disconnect". Yes, nothing stops me from adding it myself except lack of spare time (and possibly lack of skills).

Comment: If you destroy some resources along with disconnect, and the slot assuming the resources always accessable, it's gotta be a problem. you have to do some protections in your slot properly in this case.I got this trouble and that's why I'm here.